# Solve quadratic equation $2x^2-5x+4 =0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Can anyone solve the equation above since I have found that this equation is actually having no real root based on completing the square method.

Just to confirm, it actually has no roots right, since - square root is unsolved, unless it is involved with imaginary number. Can anyone help me to solve this？

Comment: You are correct.  The quadratic equation has no real roots since its discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac = 5^2 - 4 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 = -7 < 0$.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Can you use the quadratic formula? Noting that $\sqrt{-1}=i$

Comment: If you have used completing the square  method, then you may replace that negative number behind the equal sign with an $i^2$ term and then take the square roots...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no *real* roots for this equation, but there will be two complex conjugate roots.

Using the method of completing the square as a check:

$$\begin{align}
& 2x^2 - 5x + 4 = 0\\
\implies& x^2 - \frac {5}{2}x = -2\\
\implies& x^2 - \frac {5}{2}x + \frac {25}{16} = -2 + \frac {25}{16}\\
\implies& \left(x-\frac {5}{4}\right)^2 = -\frac {7}{16}\\
\implies& x-\frac {5}{4} = \pm \frac {\sqrt 7}{4}i\\
\implies& x = \frac {5}{4} \pm \frac {\sqrt {7}}{4}i\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the edit, PS - I forgot about the align function!